# SQL for customers who have purchased specific products, at a specific time

Tags: sql, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I need to identify customers who have

1. Purchased any product from the following SKUs (50076710, 50215355, 50210619, 50206711)
2. Where the last order date = Today -1 Day

I would like to pull this data from database_1.

This is what I have so far, but I'm not having any luck :(

```
SELECT
a.SubscriberKey,
a.SKU,
a.EmailAddress, 
a.FirstName,
a.LastOrderDate,
a.LasrName,
a.Domain,
a.BU, 
a.Status
FROM [database_1] as a
WHERE
a.SKU IN ('50076710','50206711','50210619','50215355') and a.LastOrderDate > dateadd(d,-1,getdate())
```

Comment: That's not "pure" Salesforce, doesn't look like SOQL query. Did you export something out of SF to SQL server? Do you use a "side product" like Marketing Cloud?

Comment: I am using Marketing Cloud!

Comment: I'm not well-versed in marketing cloud. Are you sure all data was extracted from SF? If there's some filter in the data sync task it's possible you'll get 0 results and there will be nothing wrong with your query...